# Is it possible to navigate from a page to a component of a nav-bar of another page in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am building a React Application. I have a main navigation bar with two  elements: home page and reports. Reports page has its own nav bar inside of it, which has a list of links, which when clicked are getting data from rest api and displaying it in a ag-grid.

On my home page I have a link, which when clicked I want to directly display one of the grids, which is part of the navbar of Reports page. I have used the router to specify the paths and in my home page I have imported NavLink and used it to specify the path. However it just takes me to a blank page. It seems like once it enters the second page, it cannot get inside the second navbar.

In my reports page I have created a navigation bar (WorkNavbar) and added paths to one of its elements which is called Abc. When you click on Abc you have a list of links as shown below: rose, white, etc.

```
<Router>
   <div>
   <WorkNavbar/>
   <Route  path="/reports/abc" component={Navbar2}/>
   <Route exact path="/reports/abc/rose" component= {Rose}/>
   <Route exact path="/reports/abc/white" component= {White}/>
   </div>
</Router>
```

---

In the home page i have added the link like this:

```
<NavLink to="/path2/reports/abc" className="wineslist">Rose List</NavLink>
```

but it doesn't work. The further most it takes me is to path2, which is the reports page, but it seems to not be able to enter inside the reports navbar.

How could I fix this? Any help or recommendation will be super appreciated!